# Forming a NSPredicate with a @ObservedObject wrapped property returns nothing. however, it returns the correct entries when the wrapper removed

Tags: swift, swiftui

OwnerModel is a child of NSManagedObject, when I remove the wrapper the request returns the required owner. when I leave it, it returns nothing!

```
struct OwnerCell: View {
    @ObservedObject var owner: OwnerModel    
    private var cashListView: some View {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "owner = %@", owner)
        return CashItemListView(owner: owner, request: CashItemModel.sortedFetchRequest(using: predicate))
    }

    var body: some View {
        // view code
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you initialize `owner`?

Comment: I pass to the cell in the initializer. it comes from a ForEach in a parent list view.

Comment: I feel it is something with order of initialization. You can set breakpoint at `let predicate` line and see what is the `owner` and `_owner`. Probably it could clarify the issue.